# Onchange Event of Select Box

Tags: jquery, html

I am using an `onchange event of select box` with jquery.
On change I have given `display property = none` in other div.
Problem is that when I got data from database and set it in select box so `onchange` property is not applied for given value. Why?
My code

```
<select id="patientType" name="Patient_Type">
<option value="">--SELECT--</option>
<option value="OPD">OPD</option>
<option value="IPD">IPD</option>
</select>
<div id="roomInfo" clasas="inactive"></div>
```

Script

```
$('#patientType').change(function() {
 if ($('#patientType').val() == 'IPD') {
  if ($('#roomInfo').hasClass('inactive')) {
   $('#roomInfo').removeClass('inactive');// CSS Property Display None in this class
   $('#roomInfo').addClass('active');
  }
 } else {
  if ($('#roomInfo').hasClass('active')) {
     $('#roomInfo').removeClass('active');
     $('#roomInfo').addClass('inactive');
    }
 }
});
```

now i got data From database and set it this select patientType
$('#patientType').val(data fetch From the database);
can not apply onchange event apply and not display my roomInfo div
so it is possible or not .
or another method for getting that method.
Please help.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: How you fetching the data from database? Is it ajax or in pageload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Value of Select Box and set it like this:

```
$("#patientType option[value='`OPD']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you changing the value manually. You need to trigger the .change() event of select box.
Refer the following link.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

or else

if you loading the data through ajax use like following

```
$('#patientType').on("change",function() {
   //Your code here
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers." - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

Set an change event in jQuery:

```
$("#ddl").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```